# How to use @yield and @extends in blade templates

Tags: laravel

*master.blade.php*

```
<div>
  @yield('content')
</div>
```

*index.blade.php*

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('content')
  <p>Foo</p>
@endsection
```

*Folder structure*

_layouts
__master.blade.php
_posts
__index.blade.php

When I do `return view('layouts.master')` I get nothing. I'm expecting 'Foo' to be printed.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the `index.blade.php` view, this is the view that is inheriting the layout.

```
return view('posts.index');
```